# Convert rows to columns in SSIS. Unpivot?

Tags: ssis, bids

If I have data like this

```
"","",WAREHOUSE ID,1,2,3,4,5...
"","",WAREHOUSE CODE,BOS,HOU,LAX,NYC,CHI...
"","",WAREHOUSE NAME,BOSTON,HOUSTON,LOS ANGELES,NEW YORK CITY,CHICAGO...
```

But want to transform it like this

```
 WAREHOUSE ID, WAREHOUSE CODE, WAREHOUSE NAME
 1,BOS,BOSTON
 2,HOU,HOUSTON
 3,LAX,LOS ANGELES
 ...
```

If, as above, [Column 2] is the column that contains what should be the header row, and Columns 3 through 40 contain what should be row values, which columns get selected and set to pass through for the UNPIVOT to perform the desired transposition?

Or is UNPIVOT not even what I'm looking for?

Comment: I think your approach of the first 3 rows to an `UNPIVOT` and the remaining to product should be fine. Do the first 3 need to get pushed into the database before the product rows arrive. In other words, is there a foreign key relationship that we need to respect when loading the header and body data?

Comment: There will need to eventually be a foreign key relationship. For now, though, I can't figure out how to get UNPIVOT to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: If UNPIVOT is the way to go, and Column 2 is the column that contains what should be the header row, and Columns 3 through 40 contain what should be row values, which columns get selected and set to pass through for the UNPIVOT to perform the desired transposition?

Answer (score 0):

It is technically feasible to solve the problem using one data flow. I posted the basic steps needed to [solve the same here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736108/split-fixed-width-row-into-multiple-rows-in-ssis/20591207#20591207). Having said that, its quite a bit of work to configure all the elements in the data flow.